# Помогите составить sql-запрос

Tags: php, sql

Помогите пожалуйста с SQL запросом.
 
Нужно выбрать данные из таблицы module, где `module = 'text'` и через `LEFT JOIN` сделать выборку данных из таблицы `assoc_page_module` - с этим проблем не возникло, а вот, чтобы сделать выборку данных еще и из таблицы page через, `LEFT JOIN`, у меня не получается. 
В общем нужно из таблицы Page достать все данные через какой-то `JOIN`, тут наверное нужно делать связь через `assoc_page_module.page_id = page.id`, но дело в том, что в таблице `assoc_page_module` вообще может не быть данных, и, наверное, ничего при этом не выберется из `Page`. 
Можно ли как-то решить данную задачу? 
Заджойнить `Page` через `assoc_page_module`, независимо от того, есть в ней данные для связи или нету? 
Или может как-то по другому это решается?

Таблица **module**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **assoc_page_module**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица **page**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что не так с вашим LEFT JOIN? напишите ваш запрос

Comment: lDrakonl, я Ваш запрос использовал, но та запись, которая отсутствует в assoc_page_module не заджойнилась в page и, соответственно, вернулся NULL

Comment: Обновил ответ. Попробуйте так. Если это опять не то, что надо, то напишите уже содержание таблиц и пример результата, который должен вернуться

Comment: IDrakonl, right - это не то. С ним я тоже пробовал, он просто не вернет вообще ту строку, page_id которой нет в assoc_page_module. На скрине результат того, что получилось с помощью LEFT JOIN, там средняя строка содержит NULL, а должна содержать данные из page, как, например, первая и третья строки

Comment: Просто напишите пример. Содержание таблиц и результат, который должен получиться.

Comment: IDrakonl, результат в таком формате подойдет - http://hkar.ru/GTiX ? Вместо NULL должна быть строка с id = 2 из таблицы page ( http://hkar.ru/GTjl )

Comment: Не удобно и не понятно. Вы можете просто написать текстом содержания 3х таблиц и набрать ожидаемый результат. БУдет лучше, если таким макаром вы дополните сам вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что вот так:

```
select * from module m
left join assoc_page_module apm on m.id=apm.module_id
right join Page  p on p.id=apm.page_id
where m.module = 'text'
```

`LEFT JOIN` нормально работает, если ничего нет в таблице `page`

Comment: делал уже точно такой запрос, вот что получил - http://hkar.ru/GSCu. Та страница, которая отсутствует в assoc_page_module не выбирается из Page. Надо, чтобы данные выбрались из page если в таблице assoc_page_module ничего нету, а не в том случае, если в page ничего нету

Comment: Тогда используйте RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через переменные + функцию. Функцию нужно обнулять т.к. она сохраняется.

```
set @id=7777;
set @var=(SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `main` WHERE `id`=@id) ;

DROP FUNCTION Compare;
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION Compare (n INT)
  RETURNS  VARCHAR(50)

  BEGIN
```

> если "вообще может не быть данных"

```
IF n = 0 THEN 

   INSERT INTO `main`....;


    ELSE

        SELECT * FROM `main`;


    END IF;

    RETURN n;
  END //

DELIMITER ;

SELECT Compare(@var);
```

Comment: Как то очень сложно. Можно ведь 1 запросом все сделать..

Comment: это один запрос :) первая и вторая часть

Comment: как-то громоздко получается. Наверное никак нельзя выбрать данные из page если в assoc_page_module ничего нет, ведь тогда получается, что JOIN'у не за что зацепиться